# Not rendering masonry layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-masonry

I am trying to build a masonry page with some images. here is my code

**CSS**

```
    <style>
       .masonryImage{float:left;}
    </style>
```

**JavaScript**

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script> 
    <!--<script src="<?=base_url('assets/js/bootstrap.min.js')?>"></script>-->
    <script src="<?=base_url('masonry/masonry.min.js')?>"></script>
    <script src="<?=base_url('masonry/masonry.js')?>"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var container = $('#container');
      container.imagesLoaded( function(){
          container.masonry({
            itemSelector : '.masonryImage'
          });
      });

   </script>
```

**HTML**

```
  <body id="container" style="height:100%;width:100%;background-color:#309be9;">

        <div class="masonryImage">
            <img src="http://cdn.cutestpaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/s-Playing-fetch.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="masonryImage">
            <img  src="http://cdn.cutestpaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/s-Polar-bear.jpg" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="masonryImage">
            <img  src="http://cdn.cutestpaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/s-precious.jpg" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="masonryImage">
            <img  src="http://cdn.cutestpaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/s-baby-penguin.....jpg" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="masonryImage">
            <img  src="http://cdn.cutestpaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/s-And-just-because-well-just-because-we-CAN.jpg" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="masonryImage">
            <img  src="http://cdn.cutestpaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/s-Bunnies-and-flowers...jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="masonryImage">
            <img  src="http://cdn.cutestpaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/s-captionme.jpg" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="masonryImage">
            <img  src="http://cdn.cutestpaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/s-Its-mum-is-called-Alinga..jpg" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="masonryImage">
            <img   src="http://cdn.cutestpaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/s-Curious-bobcat-cub-by-Megan-Lorenz.jpg" alt="">
        </div>

    </body>
```

I dint understand where the bug is, the page is not rendering in mansory style.

please suggest.

**UPDATE:**

After trying the two suggested javascripts the images started overlapping . Actually the code itself is not responsible for this. But something is going wrong with masonry. here is the screen shot
If you notice clearly i highlighted with a red mark, it shows some of the images and hiding!!

[image]

Ahh this is playing with me

If i try inspect element, the images are returning to their position
[image]

Too puzzeled

Comment: First of all you should check that all the masonry JavaScript files have been successfully included. Are there any errors in the console? Also try to move you JavaScript initialization in to document.ready event handler...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see an initialization of Masonny in your code:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
var $container = $('#container');
$container.masonry({
  columnWidth: 200,
  itemSelector: '.masonryImage'
});
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if your js is properly called.
Either use **masonry.min.js** or **masonry.js** it's good to use **masonry.min.js** if your are deploying. 
 To check if your **js** is called properly, view source and open the js link or place a simple alert inside your js.

**EDIT:** You seem to use [imagesloaded](http://desandro.github.io/imagesloaded/) which is not part of mansory, but can be used with mansory. If you want to initiate masonry, you have to replace your code with

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#container').masonry({
  columnWidth: 200,
  itemSelector: '.item'
  });
});
```

or with your current code you have to add [imagesloaded.js](http://desandro.github.io/imagesloaded/)

Comment: ya i checked it is calling properly, I mean i am able to view the js in Inspect element-> sources. But no luck

Comment: ok, add a simple alert at the end of your js & check if it's still working. If it still works let me know.

Comment: Ya i already checked that. It alerts as soon as the page loads